# Is there a convenient way to invert push button logic for multiple buttons at the same time?

Tags: digital-logic

I'm trying to build a circuit with ~10 push buttons and a single switch to invert their logic. I could use an XOR gate for each individual button:

[image]

but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this that uses less logic-gates.

Comment: Where do the push button signals go, where are they connected? We can't guess what is the "best" solution if we don't know the rest of the button connections.

Comment: ... Where do the ~10 switch outputs go?  Perhaps you could send an extra signal to those?

Comment: OP's "schematic" is unconventional. Electrically, what is a blue sphere surrounded by a blue square? Could it be a SPST switch? or something else? How does it generate a logic-compatible signal for those XOR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a 2P2T switch as your master positive/negative logic select.

The 2 poles would switch from High to Low supplies (one pole being the opposite of the other) and connect to your logic switches with a series resistor (that is either a pull-up, or pull-down, depending on the master switch position).

[image]

Be sure that your downstream logic is compatible with the pull-ups/downs (and the inevitable switch-glitches when the master is changing state).

Good luck!

-Chris